# Startx not automatically running on reboot

Tags: boot, x11, display, startx

When starting up by machine, I am prompted with a terminal asking me to login, rather than the nice GUI that I am use to. When I login in, I am able to run `startx` and everything works smoothly.

I added the following to my `~/zprofile` but it only ran once I was logged in.

```
if [[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]]; then
  startx
fi
```

How can I get the login screen that I am use to, to appear again?

Comment: What Ubuntu version? What is the output of `systemctl get-default` and `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`?

Comment: @steeldriver Version: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64 ` and systemctl output: `graphical.target`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gui is loaded by systemd, when the init system is systemd, this is the case of Ubuntu

Here is a nice [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) about the subject

`systemctl get-default` permit to see what target is set for the startup either `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`

To enable x at startup time you can use:

```
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

And to disable it

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Note that `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contain the default used display manager (this file is not required tho)

Also find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager) how to setup the default display manager, this is required as well

For a detailed answer more information about the setup are required (what desktop are you using kde/gnome what dm are using lightdm/sddm etc)

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. maybe install a Display Manager. Let's say LightDM.

First, you install the package ***lightdm***, then type `sudo systemctl enable lightdm` to enable it. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM for more info.

I hope this solved your problem!

EDIT: the ***lightdm*** package by itself can't launch automatically even with systemd and could mess up your system so install the ***lightdm-gtk-greeter*** package along with the ***lightdm*** package.